# CORS vs crossdomain.xml, which one has the priority?

Tags: javascript, cors, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

If my web server is configured to allow cross-origin requests in his `crossdomain.xml`, and also to deny them via `CORS` (*Access-Control-Allow-Origin: site111.org*), which configuration will be respected in the case where a website (*site222.com*) send a cross-origin HTTP request to my web server ?
As far as I understand `crossdomain.xml` is a policy file which concern only Flash requests, but not sure if CORS is appliyed in all cross-origin requests or just the ones that come from Javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CORS only affects JavaScript. crossdomain.xml only affects Flash. There is no overlap.

Comment: Tiny correction: In addition to JavaScript requests, CORS also affects cross-domain requests using @font-face in CSS. Often no biggie, but it gets forgotten too frequently.